# Why can't users access my Java website running on Windows via an IP address?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-deployment, windows-server-2012

I want to deploy a java website in google VPS. I use tomcat and I deployed it to my running location in Windows Server 2012 at

```
"localhost:8080/LocationNote/login/account"
```

but it does not run

```
"104.199.140.141:8080/LocationNote/login/account"
```

`104.199.140.141` is my server IP.

How can clients connect to

```
http://104.199.140.141:8080/LocationNote/login/account
```

Comment: add a firewall exception to server coming demands on port `8080` and you are done.

Comment: thank Rafik , i changed port to 80 and i can't connect '104.199.140.141 ', during IIS can run at port 80,

Comment: that's a bad idea , IIS is running on that port

Comment: just add firewall incoming /outcoming demans for port 8080 and it will work